# DLL - Using main project classes in library class

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I've never tried separating down my projects into DLLs but something I'm working on at the moment calls for a more modular approach. What I want to be able to do is switch out versions of a number of my classes easily to push updates to users without them having to re install my entire application.

These classes create instances of other classes which are defined within the application and shouldn't be part of the modules which are switched in and out - they're central. Obviously in the class Library project these classes are undefined as they are only defined in the main application. How do I go about enabling the class library to use these main application classes?

All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not put the "main" classes into another DLL as well?

Comment: I guess I could. Just seems a bit overkill to have to create class library projects for an expanding list of classes. Was hoping there was a simpler way. Is there a way to compile a project class into a DLL without creating another class library project in Visual Studio?

Comment: You can add multiple projects to the same solution - that will make them easier to manage and build.

Comment: @casablanca: Thankyou, this allows me to do what I need and should be easy enough to organize too.

Comment: Sound to me like you are looking for "Seperated Interface" approach. Define a set of interfaces, the "class library" implements and the "program" uses. Use reflection to create the appropriate class library based on some configuration.  (ps; Watch that .Net fusion engine. Once a library is loaded it cannot be unloaded. Destroy the AppDomain for that option)